# json to php and get variable

Tags: php, json, get, element

```js
AddNewFish=function()
{
    var formData = JSON.stringify($("#NewSubmitedFish").serializeArray());
    //var formData=$('#NewSubmitedFish').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/vidacms/add/NewFish",
        //data : {valArray:formData},
        data: 'value='+formData,
        success: function(data){
            $("#ResultFish").html(data);
        }

    });
}
```

and my php code

```
 public static function SubmitNewFish()
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $data = json_decode(json_encode($_POST['value']), True);
    //$data=json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['valArray']), true);
   // var_dump($data);
   // var_dump($_POST);
    var_dump($data);
    //print $_POST['value']['bankname'];
    /*$contract_details = $_POST['valArray'];
    $decoded = json_decode($contract_details);
    print_r($decoded);*/

}
```

nothing of my controller function working to access to variable 
with var_dump();
the result is

```
string(139) "[{"name":"bankname","value":"2"},{"name":"peygiry","value":"fish"},{"name":"payment_date","value":"9999/99/99"},{"name":"desc","value":""}]"
```

who can access this variable with value

Comment: `echo json_decode($_POST['value'], true)[0]['name'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript like this

```
AddNewFish=function()
{
    var formData = $("#NewSubmitedFish").serializeArray();
    //var formData=$('#NewSubmitedFish').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/vidacms/add/NewFish",
        data : {valArray:formData},
       // data: 'value='+formData,
        success: function(data){
            $("#ResultFish").html(data);
        }

    });
}
```

And PHP like this

```
public static function SubmitNewFish()
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $datas =json_decode($_POST['valArray'], true);//$_POST['valArray'];
    $bankname = $desc = $pay‌​ment_date = $peygiry = "";
    foreach($datas as $data)
    {
        if($data['name'] == "bankname")
        {
            $bankname = $data['value'];//$data['value'] not sure what you want
        }
        if($data['name'] == "desc")
        {
            $desc = $data['value'];//$data['value'] not sure what you want
        }
        if($data['name'] == "pay‌​ment_date")
        {
            $pay‌​ment_date = $data['value'];//$data['value'] not sure what you want
        }
        if($data['name'] == "peygiry")
        {
            $peygiry = $data['value'];//$data['value'] not sure what you want
        }
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($data);echo "</pre>";//try echo $data['name']; or echo $data['value'];
    }   
}
```

Comment: You don't need `json.stringify on serialised array $("#NewSubmitedFish").serializeArray();` Updated also...

Comment: with your php code
 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\Ampps\www\vidacms\Controllers\ShopController.php on line 252

Comment: can i access just one of the array index with out foreach like this $data['name']

Comment: i want 4 variable $bankname=$data['bankname'];$desc=$data['desc'] like this

Comment: @puriya I think you want `value` ??

Comment: @puriya Please check now

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't need to use `json_encode`, because `$_POST['value']` is json.

```
public static function SubmitNewFish()
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $data = json_decode($_POST['value'], True); //return array based on json

    //$data=json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['valArray']), true);
   // var_dump($data);
   // var_dump($_POST);
    var_dump($data);
    //print $_POST['value']['bankname'];
    /*$contract_details = $_POST['valArray'];
    $decoded = json_decode($contract_details);
    print_r($decoded);*/

}
```

Comment: how can i access this with php  in my code
string(139) "[{"name":"bankname","value":"2"},{"name":"peygiry","value":"fish"},{"name":"payment_date","value":"9999/99/99"},{"name":"desc","value":""}]"

Comment: If you need to get json as string, can use `$_POST['value']` without json functions. What's output of `var_dump($_POST['value'])`? @puriya

Comment: i want to get this bankname

Comment: You can get with `$data[0]['value']`.